# How to query duplicate objects in a many-to-many relationship with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following many-to-many relationship:

```
foos_bars = Table('foos_bars', db.metadata,
                  Column('foo_id', Integer, ForeignKey('foos_table.id')),
                  Column('bar_id', Integer, ForeignKey('bars_table.id')))


class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foos_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
    bars = db.relationship('Bar', secondary=foos_bars, back_populates='foos')


class Bar(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bars_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
    foos = db.relationship('Foo', secondary=foos_bars, back_populates='bars')
```

In the db, I have the following:

```
foos_bars:

foo_id | bar_id
-------+-------
 1     | 1
 2     | 1
 2     | 1
 3     | 2
 3     | 4
```

(in essence, I have 2<->1 twice)

If I run a raw SQL query like:

```
SELECT * from foos_bars WHERE foo_id = 2
```

I get two records (which I want).

However, in sqlalchemy:

```
Foo.query(id=2).first().bars
```

is a list that contains only one element. I would expect it to contain `Bar[1]` twice. Is there a way to do this?

This does not happen with `Foo[3]` where I get two items, as I would expect (the difference is that for Foo[3] only one side of the association is duplicated).

Comment: That is a weird many-to-many relationship. Duplicates are typically not allowed, so it is no wonder sqlalchemy cant handle them. You should have a different kind of relation. What are you trying to achieve with that duplicate relation?

Comment: @zvone Can you suggest an alternative model? In reality, "Foos" are composed of "Bars". I need to model many "Foos" that can be composed by one or more of the same "Bars" or different "Bars". For example `Foo[1] = {Bar[1]+Bar[1]}; Foo[2]={Bar[1]+Bar[2]}; Foo[3]={Bar[2]+Bar[1]+Bar[2]`